# Getting ".find('input:text').val();" but NULL ".find('div').val();"

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, loops

I have this table with an input text and an input checkbox.

```
<table id="customers">
   <tr>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>
      <div value="id" id="id"></div>
      <input type="text" style="display: none;" value="id" id="input-id" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"/>
    </td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkboxid" style="cursor: pointer"/></td>
   </tr>
```

When I try to get the input:text value, it is okay.

```
$('#customers input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
    var recorrer = $(this).closest('tr').find('input:text').val();
}
```

But when I try to get the value from the div. I get null value.

```
$('#customers input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
    var recorrer = $(this).closest('tr').find('div').val();
    alert(recorrer);
}
```

Comment: `<div>` elements don't have a "value" property. You can use `.getAttribute()` to get the non-standard attribute you've added.

Comment: A div doesn't have a `.value`, it has `.text()` or `.html()` Why even assign a `value` property to the div? Anyway, you can use `data-value="id"` then use jQuery's `.data("value")`

Comment: @ChrisG Just tried what you've said and it's working! Thank you so much!